# Mahout - Exception: Java Heap space

Tags: hadoop, mahout

I'm trying to convert some texts to mahout sequence files using:

```
mahout seqdirectory -i Lastfm-ArtistTags2007 -o seqdirectory
```

But all I get is a OutOfMemoryError, as here:

```
Running on hadoop, using /usr/bin/hadoop and HADOOP_CONF_DIR=
MAHOUT-JOB: /opt/mahout/mahout-examples-0.9-job.jar
14/04/07 16:44:34 INFO common.AbstractJob: Command line arguments: {--charset=[UTF-8], --chunkSize=[64], --endPhase=[2147483647], --fileFilterClass=[org.apache.mahout.text.PrefixAdditionFilter], --input=[Lastfm-ArtistTags2007], --keyPrefix=[], --method=[mapreduce], --output=[seqdirectoryjps], --startPhase=[0], --tempDir=[temp]}
14/04/07 16:44:35 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/04/07 16:44:35 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 4
14/04/07 16:44:35 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
14/04/07 16:44:35 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local407267609_0001
14/04/07 16:44:35 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
14/04/07 16:44:35 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local407267609_0001_m_000000_0
14/04/07 16:44:35 INFO util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code 0
14/04/07 16:44:35 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@6ad3ad65
14/04/07 16:44:35 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: Paths:/home/giuliano/cook/lastfm/Lastfm-ArtistTags2007/README.txt:0+2472,/home/giuliano/cook/lastfm/Lastfm-ArtistTags2007/ArtistTags.dat:0+71652722,/home/giuliano/cook/lastfm/Lastfm-ArtistTags2007/tags.txt:0+1739746,/home/giuliano/cook/lastfm/Lastfm-ArtistTags2007/artists.txt:0+327051
14/04/07 16:44:35 INFO compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new compressor
14/04/07 16:44:35 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Map task executor complete.
14/04/07 16:44:35 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local407267609_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:354)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable.setCapacity(BytesWritable.java:119)
    at org.apache.mahout.text.WholeFileRecordReader.nextKeyValue(WholeFileRecordReader.java:118)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileRecordReader.nextKeyValue(CombineFileRecordReader.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.MapContext.nextKeyValue(MapContext.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
14/04/07 16:44:36 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/04/07 16:44:36 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local407267609_0001
14/04/07 16:44:36 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 0
14/04/07 16:44:36 INFO driver.MahoutDriver: Program took 1749 ms (Minutes: 0.02915)
```

I am using Mahout 0.9, Hadoop 1.2.1 and OpenJDK Java7u25

defining MAHOUT_HEAPSIZE to 4096 did not help, and the text files can be found here: http://static.echonest.com/Lastfm-ArtistTags2007.tar.gz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the spawned job is executed as a local job runner, the execution happens only in the node in which you fired the job. Specify the job tracker address by setting the property  `mapred.job.tracker` in your `mapred-site.xml` inorder to make the execution distributed.

Execution in distributed mode might solve your outOfMemory issue

If you look at the environment variable `HADOOP_CONF_DIR`, its values is empty set its value using the following command `export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf`. Make sure the value of the property `mapred.job.tracker` which should point to your jobTracker in /etc/hadoop/conf/mapred-site.xml configuration

Comment: what, exactly, do I need to change? I'm not a expertise in hadoop